# Split and recombine a Python module

Tags: python, module

I have a Python module, let's call it my_lib.py which has grown too much in size and would like to split it up into two modules: lib_a.py and lib_b.py
However, the module is already used in several places:

```
import my_lib
my_lib.func_a()
my_lib.func_b()
```

In my new module partition, func_a() and func_b() end up in lib_a and lib_b respectively. I would have to change the above code to something like this:

```
import lib_a, lib_b
lib_a.func_a()
lib_b.func_b()
```

This is undesirable for backwards compatibility. What's the best way to keep referring to the two new modules as "my_lib"? Is it possible to *recombine* the two libraries into a new one called "my_lib" and keep using the legacy code?

Comment: How you tried simply `from lib_x import *`ing the two modules into `my_lib`?

Comment: I had excluded the option for a reason that is too long to explain, but I found a way around it and it seems to work. Thanks for the tip and inspiration.